# zfs files lost after upgrade to 20.04. LTS

Tags: 20.04, zfs

Today I upgraded to 20.04.1 LTS. After the reboot all my files in the zfs datasets are gone!

- I can still see and cd into the datasets but there are no files.
- I can touch a new file and see it.
- zpool status still shows the expected occupancy but df does not.
- zfs list -t snapshot shows all snapshots.
- zpool scrub is still running. Up to now with no errors.
- The files are *all* large .raw files for qemu/kvm. Typically one file per dataset.
- zfs --version is 0.8.3-lubuntu-12.4

My system consists two pairs of SSDs. The first pair carries the mdraid mirror setup for the root and boot ext4 file systems. Additionally, the major part(ition) of this pair is dedicated to a zfs pool. The second pair is completely dedicated to the zfs pool.
So no root-on-zfs issue here.

I suspect there is an issue with the zfs modules and the files are basically still there but invisible?
Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same kind of problem after an upgrade in Centos. `zfs` give a good size but no file and I become mad!

For my specific case, it seems that some service(s) create directories and subdirectories with the same name as the `zfs` storage. I unmounted `zfs`, delete the directory under `/`, remount `zfs`. Be careful before deleting files, be sure !!